# Determine whether $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15} $ can be generated by $\{(\hat{3},\overline{2}),(\hat{1},\overline{4})\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Determine whether $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15} $ can be generated by $\{(\hat{3},\overline{2}),(\hat{1},\overline{4})\}$.

What I did :

Let H be the subgroup generated by $(\hat{3},\overline{2}),(\hat{1},\overline{4})$, $H = <(\hat{3},\overline{2}),(\hat{1},\overline{4})>$ .

Proof by double inclusion:

First: Let $x \in H$ i.e $x=k_1 *(\hat{3},\overline{2})+k_2*(\hat{1},\overline{4})$ then obviously $x \in \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15} $

Second : I need to prove the reverse.

Let $(\hat{1},\overline{0}) \in \mathbb{Z}_5 x \mathbb{Z}_{15}$. Assume we can write  $(\hat{1},\overline{0}) = k_1 *(\hat{3},\overline{2})+k_2*(\hat{1},\overline{4})$. Therefore $(\hat{1},\overline{0}) = (\widehat{3k1+k2},\overline{2k_1+4k_2})$. We solve the system and we get that $k_1=\frac{2}{5}$ wich is a contradiction because $k_1$ must be in $\mathbb{Z}$.

My question is : It's that approach correct and should be done for those type of exercises ?What if I don't come up with a number like $(\hat{1},\overline{0})$

Comment: Another tip: using `\langle` and `\rangle` to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$ looks better than < and >. Not that you have to change this stuff immediately -- it's for future reference. Likewise `\|` to get $\|$ looks better than || (though you didn't use these here).

Comment: Not sure how you ended up with $k_1 = 2/5$...

Comment: You get a system 3k1+k2 = 1 and 2k1 + 4k2 = 0, solving that system leads to k1 = 2/5

Comment: @EduardValentin That is not quite correct. $k_1\hat{3} + k_2\hat{1} = \hat{1}$ means $3k_1 + k_2 = 1 + 5k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The accepted answer is, unfortunately, rather wrong. Omitting fancy little uppersigns, a first remark is that $(1,4)=2\cdot(3,2)$ (in  $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$, of course) hence $H$ is actually $H=\langle(3,2)\rangle$. Now, for $H$ to be the whole group $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$, one would need at least $(1,0)$ to be a multiple of $(3,2)$, that is, that there exists some integer $n$ such that $3n=1\bmod{5}$ and $2n=0\bmod{15}$. But $2n=0\bmod{15}$ implies $n=0\bmod{15}$ implies $n=0\bmod{5}$ implies $3n=0\bmod{5}$ implies ...

Comment: ...  $3n\ne1\bmod{5}$, hence $H\ne\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$.

Comment: ((Add here customary remarks about instantly accepting answers without checking them.))

Comment: Yea ,my bad ,I should have checked better ,thank you for the help !

Comment: I am curious about the notation: why $(\hat{a},\overline{b})$ instead of $(a,b)$? The extra symbols don't seem to add anything useful here. Also, it's strange to say, "Let $(\hat{1},\overline{0}) \in \mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$" because "let" is normally used to speak of variables. (It would be like saying, "Let $19 \in \mathbb R$.") A better word would be, for example, "Consider ..."